# Link Server Error - From SQL2008r2 to SQL2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I'm getting the following error when I try to query a table using a link server.
The link server is created on SQL2008r2 instance to connect to an SQL2014 instance.

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server\SQL2014"
>   does not contain the table ""db_name"."dbo"."table_name"". The table
>   either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on
>   that table.

Here is the TSQL i'm using to create the link server

```
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'server\SQL2014', @srvproduct=N'sql_server', @provider=N'SQLNCLI10'

EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='server\SQL2014', @useself='false',@rmtuser='sa', @rmtpassword='sa_password'
```

When I test the connection that succeeds

The linked server login is **sa** so permissions can't be an issue.

sa user is enabled and table exists i can connect to and query all the tables directly on the SQL2014 instance using the sa user.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you verified that there is 'sa' enabled, the table exists?

Comment: You should avoid using any user that is part of the **sysadmin** fixed server role as your linked server user.  This is going to open up all manner of security holes.  I know it's not your question, but I bring it up since you're troubleshooting, I would suggest you create a new SQL Login on the destination server with permissions only *as needed* and use that account to establish the connection.

Comment: This is on development.
sa user is enabled and table exists
i can connect to and query all the tables directly on the SQL2008r2 instance using the sa user

Comment: Are you using the correct syntax  [LINKED_SERVER].[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]?

Comment: yes I am @McNets

Comment: If you use four part syntak: for example: [ServerName].[DB_Name].[dbo].[TableName]. Additionally, could you check whether we can see the table with SQL Server Management Studio under Linked Servers. If so, please right click the table, “Script table as”,  “Select To”, “New Query Window” to generate the query codes.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze, you said 2 times "i can connect to and query all the tables directly on the SQL2008r2 instance using the sa user", but the table in question should exist on 2014 instance, not on SQL2008r2.

Comment: My bad, I've clarified the question. @CR241 Yes, I'm using the 4 part syntax.  and the table exists in SSMS under Linked Servers

Answer (score 1):

Please try specifying the **@datasrc** parameter when you create a linked server, e.g.

```
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'server\SQL2014', 
@srvproduct=N'sql_server', @provider=N'SQLNCLI10', 
@datasrc = N'server\SQL2014'
```

The confusion may lie with the **@server** parameter being a descriptive name of the linked server to use in your code.  **@datasrc** is actually physical server name used by OLEDB to make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the connection and use SA, It seems you don't use correct syntax (Linkserver.Database. Schema.TableName) or the part of syntax like table name don't exist or mismatch table name...